# How to extract sub string of variable length using Python

Tags: python, substring

I am retrieving data by reading multi line python string.

My string is shown below:

```
Hostname: windos
Model: OS_5000
OS: 18.2
OS Kernel 64-bit  [2020_Stable]
....
.....
....
```

I am looking to extract Model value i.e. 5000 from this string. Not sure how to do it.

```
 dpath = op.response()
                    dpath = dpath[dpath.find("Model:")+ 6 : dpath[dpath.find("Model:")+ 11]
```

Also, model string could be of variable length. Is there any better way of doing it?

EDIT: Model value could be numeric or non-numeric.

Comment: After you've found the start of the model number, find the first newline (`"\n"`) after that position (`str.find()` takes an optional second parameter to specify the starting position to search).  Use that position as the end of your slice.

Comment: We need to know what assumptions we can make about string that are safe.

Comment: We need to extract till end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

re.search('Model: (.*)', dpath).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try :** `(using Regex)`

```
import re
s = """Hostname: windos
Model: 5000
OS: 18.2
OS Kernel 64-bit  [2020_Stable]"""
match = re.search('Model: (\d+)', s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

---

```
5000
```

---

If multiple `Model` in the string:

```
import re
s = """Hostname: windos
Model: 5000
OS: 18.2
Model: 12343434
OS Kernel 64-bit  [2020_Stable]"""
match = re.findall('Model: (\d+)', s)
if match:
    print(match)
```

---

```
['5000', '12343434']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression:

```
import re
model = re.findall('model\:\s*(\d+)', dpath, re.I)
if model:
    model = model[0]
```

Here I use "re.I" to search case insensitive word "model"
"\s*" — means if there will be some space after the colon or not it won't break this script.
So it find numbers in next cases:
Model: 5000
Model:5000
model: 5000
model:   5000

Comment: Thanks: But model could be non numeric as well. How to cover this case?

Comment: use `\w+` then  in place of `\d+`

Comment: @Ammad very simple: 'model\:\s*(\S+)'
'\S' – means non space symbol